# Wordpress Ajax Not Outputting Buffers When In Nopriv Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

A conundrum: my Wordpress ajax action hooks are only outputting their buffers when called via the `wp_ajax_(action)` action hook, but not `wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)`. My Ajax handler still fires for both hooks, and performs all the necessary backend work regardless of which was used, with the sole deviance being output vs. no output.

The two are hooked into properly and identically:

```
if ( is_admin() ) {

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_clfhn', 'clfhn_ajax' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_clfhn', 'clfhn_ajax' );

    //...
```

Calls to the `clfhn` action all get routed to the correct function, which then processes the request via a controller object:

```
function clfhn_ajax() {

    ignore_user_abort( true );

    ob_start();

        $ajax_controller = new AjaxController();
        $result = $ajax_controller->process_request();
        echo json_encode( $response, $ajax_controller->numeric_check );

    header( 'Connection: close' );
    header( 'content-type: application/json' );
    header( 'Content-Length: ' . ob_get_length() );

    // This dumps the buffer contents to a debug file
    \tools\dump( ob_get_contents() );

    while ( @ob_end_flush() );
    exit;

}
```

I use an output buffer and calculate its expected length because there are several after-output actions that are triggered in shutdown functions and take significant amounts of time to complete. This way the user gets the success/failure reply back immediately.

For both the priv *and* nopriv ajax requests, all requests send back `200` with correctly calculated content lengths, the `\tools\dump` log file is filled with properly formatted results, and all after-exit tasks are completed normally. `AjaxController::process_request()` does not access any privileged functions or depend on the user at all, and the `wp_ajax` action does not echo out "-1" or "0", nor are there any server errors or warnings logged. Actions sent from logged-in pages echo out and return good JSON results. Actions sent from logged-out pages get sent nothing, 0 bytes, and the browser reports an unexpected end of data at line 1, col 1. The rest of the shutdown functions fire, and as expected, about 1 minute after the browser shows the request complete the final log file shows all tasks finished.

I've been going over every line of code and have about a billion breakpoints along the entire execution path. Every point seems to check out, right up until it's supposed to hit the browser. Again, even the stuff that happens after all the outputs are supposed to be sent happens correctly.

Ideas?

Comment: have you seen something different between priv and nopriv in the network monitor ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Comment: Nope - both requests send exactly the same headers and parameters, and get back the _exact_ same headers too. The nopriv response body is just completely empty.